# Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('T')

Tags: c#, .net

Why oh why is this not allowed:

```
    private static unsafe byte[] ConvertStruct<T>(T str) where T: struct
    {
        T* ptr = &str;
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        var arr = new byte[size];
        Marshal.Copy((IntPtr) ptr, arr, 0, size);
        return arr;
    }
```

I get the compile error "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('T')"

Or is the "struct" constraint not enough? In the sense that it could still be an managed struct?

Do I understand correctly that my struct might not be blittable? If so, should blittable not be a valid constraint?

Comment: You can only make a pointer to a struct if that struct only has unmanaged members (aka no fields of class types or such). Seeing as a generic can't restrict the type to only structs that pass this rule, the compiler has no choice but to disallow it entirely.

Comment: As of [C# 7.3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/06/12/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3) you will be able to use `where T : unmanaged`.

Comment: NOTE: for anyone who wants to look at the addresses to make sure they understand what is happening under the hood, PLEASE watch these two videos instead of racking your brain on this. (VIDEO 1: youtube.com/watch?v=h6aXzd1nTXQ ) (VIDEO 2: youtube.com/watch?v=mvieNUe9Urs ). This gave me everything I wanted to know. I came from a C++ background became incredibly frustrated when i couldn't freely look at the memory address using the watch window. When discussing memory, it is so useful to have a visual understanding about what is going on in the background.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like Damian_The_Unbeliever said, you can't make an unmanaged pointer of a managed object or of a struct that contains managed fields. And like I said in the comment, there is no generic restraint that you can implement that would ensure compile-time safety to make sure the struct would satisfy those requirements. As such, you can't make a pointer to a generic type.

There may be a workaround, however. The [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zhzfk83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method will take a structure object and copy its data into an `IntPtr` address. You can use it in conjunction with `Marshall.AllocHGlobal` to possibly achieve your desired functionality:

```
private static byte[] ConvertStruct<T>(ref T str) where T : struct
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
    IntPtr arrPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, arrPtr, true);
    var arr = new byte[size];
    Marshal.Copy(arrPtr, arr, 0, size);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(arrPtr);
    return arr;
}
```

---

As Kris Vandermotten points out, the `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` isn't actually necessary. You can pin the array, get an `IntPtr` for it, and copy to the `IntPtr` directly:

```
private static unsafe byte[] ConvertStruct<T>(ref T str) where T : struct
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
    var arr = new byte[size];

    fixed (byte* arrPtr = arr)
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, (IntPtr)arrPtr, true);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

The benefit to the first method, though, is that it doesn't require an `unsafe` context to work. (If you care about that kind of thing.)

Comment: You are on to something with `Marshal.StructureToPtr`, but I don't think you need `AllocHGlobal` and can instead copy to the managed array directly if you pin it. Also, if you do allocate memory with `AllocHGlobal`, make sure to also free it with `FreeHGlobal`.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Nice call. I was trying to figure out how to get the pointer for the array and completely forgot about pinning.

Comment: Also, OP's signature causes a copy of the struct. If it's passed by reference, that copy can be avoided too. `static unsafe byte[] ConvertStruct<T>(ref T str) where T : struct`

Answer (score 5):

From C# Spec, section 18.2:

> a pointer is not permitted to point to a reference or to a struct that contains references, and the referent type of a pointer must be an *unmanaged-type.*
>
> ...
>
> an *unmanaged-type* is one of the following:
>
> • `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, or `bool`.
>
> • Any *enum-type*.
>
> • Any *pointer-type*.
>
> • Any user-defined *struct-type* that is not a constructed type and contains fields of *unmanaged-types* only.

And there's no real way to express this via generic constraints. Even if this definition does seem substantially similar to any definition of ["blittable"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7(v=vs.110).aspx), it's notable that that specific concept isn't defined (or even referenced) in the C# Spec. For instance, from the MSDN page we can see that "one dimensional array of a blittable type" is blittable but the above spec definition seems to preclude arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. With marshalling you can avoid unsafe keyword

```
 private static byte[] ConvertStruct<T>(T str) where T : struct
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);//sizeof
        int ptr = (int)Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);//allocate memory before past the structure there
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, (IntPtr)ptr, true);//alloc your structure
        byte[] res=new byte[size];//your result
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            res[i] = Marshal.ReadByte((IntPtr)ptr);//read byte from memory
            ptr++;//offset
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Also, you'll need to set a StructLayout attribute in your structure, as it's shown below

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[Serializable]
public struct StrStruct
{}
```

If your structure contains fields with umnmanaged types, use [MarshalAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to marshal all your fields with unmamaged types properly (ex. string as an LPWStr). If your structure is completely unmanaged, you need to marshal all of its fields with MarshalAs.

Comment: Seems like this would be slower, no? Is Marshal.StructureToPtr also a simple low-level byte copy, or does it reflect on all the properties of the struct?

Comment: LayoutKind.Sequential, I guess, just copying field values into memory with their definition order. That's why we use Marshal.PtrToSctucture or Marshal.Copy after StructureToPtr. But yes, Marshal.Copy is faster than mine buffer reading.