# Marshal Reads a structure from a ushort array C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am trying to read the structure from the byte array:

```
var data = new ushort[10]{65535, 65535, 65535 ...};
var datashort = ChangeUshortToShort(data);
FromArray(datashort )
```

And my structur:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public class Failures
{
    public ushort cardTrErr;
    public uint TrErr;
    public uint KsrErr;
    public ushort sh6;
    public ushort sh12;
    public ushort blockade;
    public ushort biz;
    public ushort blockadeInPerm;

    public virtual byte[] ToArray()
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(this, ptr, false);
        byte[] array = new byte[size];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, array, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return array;
    }

    public virtual void FromArray(short[] val)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(val.ToArray(), 0, ptr, size);
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, this);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
    public short[] ChangeUshortToShort(ushort[] val)
    {
        List<short> list = new List<short>();
        foreach (var item in val)
        {
            list.Add((short)(item & 0xFF));
            list.Add((short)(item >> 8));
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Method ChangeUshortToShort return array with all values 255.

When I do ToArray() it to return 255. But if I do it FromArray() it assigns 255 value for ushort when should 65535. And assigns 16711935 for uint when should be 4294967295.

I think i should use attributes MarshalAs, but dont know how. Can someone help me?

**Edit:**

Second structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Flags
{
    public ushort frameCnt;
    public ushort progVersion;
    public byte algUM;
    public byte deviceNumber;
    public _alg_1U _alg_1U;
    public ushort OUTPUTS;
    public _statS _StatS1;
    public _statS2 _StatS2;
    //public ushort _StatS1;
    //public ushort _StatS2;
    public ushort nbLector;
    public ushort nbSignal;
    public byte comBlockadeT1;
    public byte comBlockadeT2;
    public _permS permS;
    //public ushort permS;
    public ushort permHistory;
    public ushort stopInfo;
    public _controlFlagsS _controlFlagsS;
    //public ushort _controlFlagsS;
    public ushort timerInfo;
    public ushort timerTrDiagCycle;
    public ushort sizeOfStruct;
    public ushort methanSensorValue1;
    public ushort methanSensorValue2;
    public ushort methanSensorValue3;
    public ushort methanSensorValue4;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct _alg_1U
{
    public byte PZP1;
    public byte PZP2;
    public byte PZS;
    public byte PZZ1;
    public byte PZZ2;
    public byte PZZ3;
    public byte KB1;
    public byte KB2;
    public byte KRU;
    public byte reserved;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct _statS
{
    public bool SYS_AW;
    public bool SYS_BK;
    public bool SYS_READY;
    public bool SYS_WORK;
    public bool PT_WORK;
    public bool DISPATCHER_ON_LINE;
    public bool SYS_STARTING;
    public bool LEKTOR_ERROR;
    public bool SYS_BK_KSR;
    public bool SYS_READY_LEKTOR;
    public bool SYS_INIT;
    public bool KRU_WORK;
    public bool SIG_RES_DIODA;
    public bool SIG_RES_BK_KSR;
    public bool SIG_RES_WORK;
    public bool unUse16;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct _statS2
{
    public bool R1;
    public bool R2;
    public bool SAG_DISABLED;
    public bool unUse4;
    public bool unUse5;
    public bool unUse6;
    public bool unUse7;
    public bool unUse8;
    public bool unUse9;
    public bool unUse10;
    public bool unUse11;
    public bool unUse12;
    public bool unUse13;
    public bool unUse14;
    public bool unUse15;
    public bool unUse16;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct _permS
{
    public bool PZP1;
    public bool PZP2;
    public bool PZS;
    public bool PZZ1;
    public bool PZZ2;
    public bool PZZ3;
    public bool KOMBAJN1;
    public bool KOMBAJN2;
    public bool KRU;
    public bool PT;
    public bool unUse11;
    public bool unUse12;
    public bool unUse13;
    public bool unUse14;
    public bool unUse15;
    public bool unUse16;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct _controlFlagsS
{
    public bool confSaved;
    public bool confFrameErr;
    public bool confDataErr;
    public bool passSaved;
    public bool passFrameErr;
    public bool unUse6;
    public bool unUse7;
    public bool unUse8;
    public bool unUse9;
    public bool unUse10;
    public bool unUse11;
    public bool unUse12;
    public bool unUse13;
    public bool unUse14;
    public bool unUse15;
    public bool unUse16;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `ChangeUshortToShort` method doesn't do what you expect: a short and ushort both have 2 bytes, but `ChangeUshortToShort` will turn each ushort into 2 shorts, i.e. it will double the number of bytes

Comment: "When I do ToArray() it to return 255." - what does that even mean? `ToArray` returns an array - do yoy mean 255 bytes? or?

Comment: @MarcGravell it return array short[20] with all value 255

Comment: @canton7 it really doesn't make sense. I got lost with this task.

Comment: @SilnyToJa I don't think you've really *defined what you are trying to do*; frankly, using `short`/`ushort` here is pretty unusual in the first place: when talking about payloads, we usually deal in `byte` - but switching between sizes *is possible*. I think this flows from the very first line of your question: "I am trying to read the structure from the byte array:" - when the thing you post next *isn't a byte array* (in the general case, it isn't even well-defined in terms of content unless we also discuss endianness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to re-interpret the 20 bytes of data directly, they you're *probably* doing things the hard way; consider:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct Failures
{
    public ushort cardTrErr;
    public uint TrErr;
    public uint KsrErr;
    public ushort sh6;
    public ushort sh12;
    public ushort blockade;
    public ushort biz;
    public ushort blockadeInPerm;
}
static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new ushort[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length;i++) data[i] = 65535;

        // re-interpret
        Failures failures = MemoryMarshal.AsRef<Failures>(
            MemoryMarshal.Cast<ushort, byte>(data));
        // show the data
        Console.WriteLine(failures.cardTrErr);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.TrErr);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.KsrErr);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.sh6);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.sh12);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.blockade);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.biz);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.blockadeInPerm);
    }
}
```

Note, however, that re-interpret casts like this are an endianness nightmare; it would be worth making some CPU-endianness assertions, *at a minimum* (i.e. if the data is little-endian, throw an exception if your CPU *isn't*)

If you don't have access to spans, the same result can be achieved via `unsafe`:

```cs
        Failures failures;
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (ushort* ptr = data)
            {   // re-interpret
                failures = *(Failures*)ptr;
            }
        }
        // show the data
        Console.WriteLine(failures.cardTrErr);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.TrErr);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.KsrErr);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.sh6);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.sh12);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.blockade);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.biz);
        Console.WriteLine(failures.blockadeInPerm);
```

Comment: I want to test it, but dont have any using for MemoryMarshal. Is this some kind of library?

Comment: @SilnyToJa I posted an edit that shows how to do it without that (using `unsafe` instead), but: `MemoryMarshal` is part of the main runtime now - on older frameworks, it might be in the `System.Memory` NuGet package (but honestly: it would be better to just use an up-to-date .NET version, i.e. .NET Core 3.1 or .NET 5, at time of writing)

Comment: I cant use net 5. At last it seem to work when i use Marshal.StructureToPtr(failures, (IntPtr)ptr, true); because failures = *(Failures*)ptr; throw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154908/cannot-take-the-address-of-get-the-size-of-or-declare-a-pointer-to-a-managed-t

Comment: @SilnyToJa did you see that I changed the type to `struct`? that wasn't accidental

Comment: Can I ask you something else? Should it also work on more complex structures? Now I have structur, with type ushort, byte and type other structure which have type: byte or bool. And unfortunately it doesn't interpret everything to max value when it passes arrays with values of 65535; When i throw struct with bool value it work, but I need value 0/1

Comment: @SilnyToJa you would need to be *very* specific about the layout for me to answer that. A `bool` field is stored as an octet, for example - and by default, "padding" and order can be important - but you can control the layout using `[FieldOffset(...)]`. If you have an example that shows exactly which fields you intend to match to which inputs, I can probably help. Once again, though: a) endianness matters, and b: it is *really* unusual to talk in terms of a `ushort[]` input rather than a `byte[]` input.

Comment: I added this struct. If you would like help. And for this struct i have ushort[25] array;

Comment: @SilnyToJa the missing piece there is that you can't have all bool *fields* - as I said: a bool field is an octet; instead, you need a composite field that you then apply bit-mapping to, via properties; I've given [an example here](https://gist.github.com/mgravell/f8c6a3f9ebbecd9fc6ab30a0ef850e17), which gives the correct size of 50 bytes (`ushort[25]` is 50 bytes). However! You'd need to check the bit ordering to make sure that the bits are laid out in the way you expect, and I've cheated and only done bit-mapping to one of the four example structs, so there's some work for you to do.

Comment: @SilnyToJa ooh, there's actually a **MUCH EASIER** way to do the bit-mapping; one second, I'll do a better example

Comment: @SilnyToJa here's the much easier way - using `[Flags]` enums that are defined as 16-bits (`: ushort`). Note: you **still** need to manually check the layout, and note that endianness means that the octets may appear swapped, so: you're going to need to very carefully check the bits are in the right positions (in the enums - just change the `<< {number}`): https://gist.github.com/mgravell/1d80f94900c15671a7ff2b4f1bbe201d

Comment: I tested, two ways work, the second one has a shorter notation for the structure, but it is more complicated to reference Flags._StatS1.HasFlag (_statS.SYS_AW); In my program, I will do a lot of conditions for some values and it seems that it will be easier to do it in the first way. Thank you very much for your help.